# Shows "Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>" while retrieving data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've been trying to retrieve all data from model **StudentInfo**. 
But it shows the following error.

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column student_studentinfo.gurdians_mobile does not exist
>   allStudent
>   Error in formatting: ProgrammingError: column student_studentinfo.gurdians_mobile does not exist
>   LINE 1: ...ile_no1", "student_studentinfo"."current_address", "student_s...

After debugging my code, I found the line that causes error is

> allStudent = StudentInfo.objects.all()

And the debugging messages Shows:

> Unable to get repr for class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'

Here is my model **StudentInfo**

```
class StudentInfo(models.Model):
    student_name = models.CharField("Student Name",max_length=20)
    admission_date = models.DateField("Admission Date")
    mobile_no1 = models.CharField("Mobile No.",max_length=12)
    current_address = models.CharField("Current Address",max_length=20,blank=True)
    batch_number = models.ForeignKey(BatchInfo)
    coaching_id = models.IntegerField("Coaching ID")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.student_name

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.student_name)
```

And the other model **BatchInfo** that is related to **StudentInfo**

```
class BatchInfo(models.Model):
    batch_name = models.CharField("Batch Name",max_length=20)
    batch_started_from = models.DateField("Batch Started From")
    no_of_registered_student = models.IntegerField("Number of Registered Student so far",default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.batch_name
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.batch_name
```

The strange part is that I've used the same style of code in other places which are perfectly functioning.

> all_batch = BatchInfo.objects.all()

I try my best to solve it by my own but as a newbie, I found it very difficult for me. So I ask your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please always provide the full traceback when you are asking for troubleshooting assistance.

Comment: @EmettSpeer Added few more traceback report. I hope it will enough to findout the problem

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Ho did you resolved it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So what I've learned so far about this problem is that there is no definitive answer exists for this particular type of problem. Django shows this error for multiple reasons. So I'm going to list all the scenarios and solutions that I've came across so far for this problem:

1. This problem might arise if you try to filter or access a field that does not exist in your model declaration.
2. **Dirty Model Migration** :P **:** As a beginner this was my nightmare. And most of the time I got this error for improper migration. So in case if you haven't migrated your model changes properly then you will get this error for sure. And to fix this problem you have to reset migration. To do this you can check the following link:
   https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/26/how-to-reset-migrations.html

*Note: I'll keep this answer updated once I get new scenario and their                solution.*

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using Python 3.x

Change your

```
def __unicode__(self):
```

to

```
def __str__(self):
```

Comment: Nope its didn't work. I've tried with __str__() but it doesn't work.

Comment: your edit changes the entire question. Your debug info has nothing to do with the error message. Have you run the migrations properly ?

Comment: Yes I've migrate properly. and its show everything ok

Answer (score 0):

These problems arise when you have a problem with your DB.
Very excellent answer by @Shubho Shaha. I encounter the same problem and I debug it by following method.

```
class G(models.Model):
      subscription_startdate = models.DateField(default=timezone.datetime.today().date()) 
      ...
      ...
```

I tried to access each field separately using `.values` and I found a problem with my DateField column because I assign wrong default value

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem due to bad variable naming. In my case:

```
class SomeModel(models.Model):
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, .....)
    #  other fields ...
    #       .
    #       .
    #       .
```

The issue here is that I named the field user with capital 'U', i-e "User", which is actually the name of my django custom User Model, which, for some reason, django didn't like that and and got angry :p.

So I simply made the user field lower case, i-e :

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, .....)  # User --> user
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was simple.

```
class Report(TimestampedModel):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    report_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    sector = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
        return self.project_name
```

What caused my issue was that I was using a field (project_name) that was not part of the model fields. So I changed it to what was in the model and I stopped getting the error. .

```
def __str__(self):
        return self.sector
```

This is how my problem got fixed.

**Update**
Another cause for the above issue as I found out [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/3ee5j8/help_stackoverflow_has_failed_me_unable_to_get/) is that the returned data from the def **str**(self) method should be a string. Anything other than that will throw the above error.

A fix can be to convert the data type of what youre returning to a string like this;

```
def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date_answered)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you do not specify the model name correctly in the serilizer. In my case this was the mistaken, and when i corrected it, it worked. here is an example;
model code

```
class ResourcesChosen(models.Model):
    resources = models.ForeignKey(Resource, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Polls, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    appusers = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    farmers = models.ForeignKey(Farmer, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=7, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=11, decimal_places=7, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.resources
```

Serializer code

```
class ResourcesChosenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Replies
        fields = (
            'id',
            'resources'
            'poll'
            'appusers',
            'farmers',
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
        )
```

As you can see, the model name is different from what i specified in the model and that was causing issues. The correct way is;

```
class ResourcesChosenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ResourcesChosen
        fields = (
            'id',
            'resources'
            'poll'
            'appusers',
            'farmers',
            'latitude',
            'longitude',
        )
```

This fix eliminated the problem, "Unable to get repr for <class 'django.db.models.query.QuerySet'>" while retrieving data